# Multiple Language support in iOS app

Tags: ios, api

I have successfully integrated Localization to support multiple languages in my App. The problem is that how can I change the language of the data coming from API?

Comment: means you need multiple language data from api?

Comment: You should send a language parameter to the api so it can send you the response in that language.

Answer (score 0):

You have to localize your API. Can you tell more about the API you want to translate ?